# Can I separate text in a column based on there being either one or more than one word?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a column headed 'Name' in sheet 'Imported'. This is auto populated with either just a first name or a full name. I would like to move the data from this column into column T of another sheet called 'Road MT" if it's a full name or column U of that sheet if it's only a first name.

Currently the data from the Name column goes into column T of the other sheet and if required I manually move it to column U.

```
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('T2').activate();

 spreadsheet.getRange('Imported!J2:J').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
    SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    }
```

Comment: Without being able to see the data in your spreadsheet I might guess that you could split the data on space and then check to see what the length is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function names(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var names = ss.getRange("C1:C4").getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    if (/\s/.test(names[i]))
      ss.getRange("C"+(i+1)).moveTo(ss.getRange("D"+(i+1)));
  }
}
```

It will look at the values in the range provided (`C1:C4` in this case) and check for a whitespace in the cells (which should be there if there are two names). If found, it will move these values to the corresponding row in `D` column.